# Does rfkill have any additional effect on hardware compared to ifconfig?

Tags: wifi, hardware

As far as I know, running `ifconfig wlan0 down` disables all communication via that wireless network interface. But what happens if I run `rfkill block wifi` afterwards? Does `rfkill` merely prevent the interface from going up again until I unblock it, or does it have an additional effect on the WLAN hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `rfkill` has an additional effect on hardware: it physically (or rather electrically) disables WLAN, Bluetooth etc., so that it's impossible to send (or receive) anything on those frequences. Important e.g. on a plane where using such things is not allowed, or anywhere else where you must be sure to not produce noticeable EM waves. Also important on laptops when you want to conserve power.

If you just disable the interface, the firmware may still decide that it wants to use power to receive signals so it can update the internal state, or it may even send administrative signals from time to time.

Comment: Thanks. The [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ifconfig/) says that `ifconfig` will attempt to reset  the interface in order to disable all transmission / reception. Is that insufficient, or different from what `rfkill` would do?

Comment: It depends on the firmware. It *should* be sufficient, but I wouldn't bet on it. And yes, it's different from what `rfkill` does, as I tried to explain in the answer. You can see the difference on laptops: with `rfkill`, the WLAN LED goes off (because it's disabled physically). Setting the interface to down doesn't affect the WLAN LED in any way.

Comment: IMO on laptops the WLAN LED is not connected to actual WLAN adapter in any way. On USB WLAN adapters (at least the ones I have) the LEDs go down when I put the interface down.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: well, at least on my laptop the WLAN LED is connected to the circuitry that kills the complete interface. YMMV.

Comment: May I ask which laptop that is?